# Why does React not render anything when using map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I want to return and render `<li>` elements containing the titles of fetched stores, but only the bullets from `<li>` components show with no content.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
    const [stores, setStores] = new useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = new useState(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = new useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getStores = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch("https://www.cheapshark.com/api/1.0/stores");
                if (!response.ok) throw new Error(`Error: ${response.status}`);

                let data = await response.json();
                console.log(data);
                setStores(data);
                setError(null);
            }
            catch(err) {
                setError(err.message);
                setStores(null);
            }
            finally {
                setIsLoading(false);
            }  
        }
        
        getStores()
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Stores</h1>
            {isLoading && <div>A moment please...</div>}
            {error && <div>{`Error while fething data from API: ${error}`}</div>}

            <ul>
                {stores &&
                stores.map(store => (
                    <>
                        <li key={store.storeID}>{store.storeName}</li>
                        <img src={store.images.banner} />
                    </>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
```

I tried rewriting the map function numerous times, but to no avail. This is my first experience with React, so I don't know what I may be doing wrong.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You can try to set default values to stores by array not by null const [stores, setStores] = useState([]); , and verify if ajax get values true

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `new` from your `useState`.

So instead of:

```
  const [stores, setStores] = new useState(null);
```

you should use:

```
  const [stores, setStores] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
```

Comment: Your are right jhon!

Comment: That was not the case though. I did it and the problem remains.

Comment: The code is fine once you've removed the `new` from your `useState`, so now it must be the data that gets collected. Can you post what you get from that `console.log(data);` please?

Comment: Yes, you are right. There was another mistake on my side. It all works now. Thank you.